# Ruby code for openssl to generate fingerprint

Tags: ruby, openssl, base64, sha1, fingerprint

I need the ruby equivalent of the following:

```
openssl x509 -sha1 -fingerprint -noout -in cert.pem
```

The code that I wrote is:

```
data = File.read("cert.pem")
data["-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"]=""
data["-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"]=""
OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new(Base64.encode64(data))
```

This code does not generate the same fingerprint as the openssl cli command does.

Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 10):

As gtrig mentions, the OpenSSL command line builds the fingerprint by hashing the DER encoding of the certificate, not the Base64 PEM representation. You can parse this using pure OpenSSL:

```
file_data = File.read("cert.pem")
cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(file_data)
puts OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new(cert.to_der).to_s
```

Shameless plug: [r509](http://github.com/reaperhulk/r509) can also do this like so:

```
cert = R509::Cert.load_from_file("cert.pem")
puts cert.fingerprint('sha1')
```

If you need it to be in colon separated form you can just take the hash and do something like `"fingerprint".scan(/../).map{ |s| s.upcase }.join(":")`

Comment: FWIW, a PKCS12 cert object (from a pfx file) has to have its certificate member extracted for the checksum, so the last line would be: OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new(cert.certificate.to_der).to_s

Comment: I know this thread is an old one, hoping someone will reply. For a SHA256 certificate, do I need to calculate the digest as SHA256?
    `puts OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new(cert.to_der).to_s`

Comment: @SickLickWill No, SHA1 here indicates the algorithm used to generate the fingerprint itself and has no relationship to the hashing algorithm used in the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Try Base64.decode64.

```
OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new(Base64.decode64(data))
```

Certificates in PEM format are Base 64 encoded versions of a binary DER format, so they need to be DEcoded before the SHA1 hash is taken.

Alternatively, you could convert the PEM file to DER format with OpenSSL like this:

```
openssl x509 -in cert.pem -out cert.der -outform der
```

Then your Ruby code would look like this:

```
 data2 = File.read("cert.der")
 print OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new(data2)
```

Either way works.